# How do I list a custom field and custom taxonomies for each result in a loop?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, loop

How do I list a custom field and custom taxonomies for each result in my loop below?

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=customtype&showposts=10'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

the_title(); // <- works
//list custom field here
//list custom taxonomy here

endwhile;

wp_pagenavi();              
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get custom field values with `get_post_meta`.  Like so...

```
<?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=customtype&showposts=10'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

the_title(); // <- works
if( $some_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'the_meta_key_you_want', true )
{
    // you could put other formatting here.
    echo $some_meta; 
}

endwhile;
```

You'll need to change `the_meta_key_you_want` in the call to [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), of course.

For a custom taxonomy, you'll want to use [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) or [`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms). `the_terms` is a bit more like `the_tags` or `the_category`, it spits out HTML for you.  `get_the_terms` will just return an array (a list) of the term objects.

Here's an example of `get_the_terms`.  The Codex entry for it also has some good examples.  You'll have to change `your_taxonomy`, of course.

```
<?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=customtype&showposts=10'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

the_title(); // <- works
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your_taxonomy' );
if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) )
{
    foreach( $terms as $t )
    {
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $t->slug, 'your_taxonomy' ) . '">' . esc_html( $t->name ) . '</a>';
    }
}

endwhile;
```

Comment: Awesome. The taxonomy one works. But why am I getting a white screen of death on the get_post_meta one.

Comment: Try now. I didn't capitalize the `ID` property of `$post`.

Comment: Found out that you need to use "get_the_id()" instead of "$post->ID" in "get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'the_meta_key_you_want', true );"

Comment: ... if you want to update your original post to include my last comment I would love to give you the points! Also, make sure you change "$term->name" to "$t->name".

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `get_the_ID`, but it's changed.